# Drupal features gives error PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column does not exist

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

When I try to revert or recreate a feature in Drupal, it gives me this error. `"PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column 'field_xyz_shared_contact_target_type' doesn't exist in table: ALTER TABLE {field_data_field_shared_contact} ADD INDEX`field_xyz_shared_contact_target_entity`(`field_xyz_shared_contact_target_type`,`field_xyz_shared_contact_target_id`); Array ( ) in db_add_index() (line 2944 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mycompany/drupal/project/data/drupal7/includes/database/database.inc)".` This missing field which Drupal is complaining about is an entity reference field.

How can I fix it? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to update the database before working with that feature? It looks like some hook_update_N function tries to add an index and the feature module calls that function

Comment: Thank you for youre reply. Yes I tried to update DB and it says no database updates found.